# Insert build step to modify generated WPF code

Tags: c#, wpf, compiler-construction, msbuild, code-generation

I want to insert a build step which modifies the generated code from the Microsoft tools, before it compiles (especially the .g.cs files). For this I think I can use the Target "BeforeCompile" (hopefully). But now I have a problem, my tool which I run needs to know the version of the assembly which is generated! Is there a way to get this version as a command-line switch to my tool?

Comment: What do you want this for? really REALLY sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I need to modify the generated cs files of the Wpf CodeGenerator to include the Version String of the geratéd Dll..

This should be another Solution for a fix I explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152965/wpf-use-different-versions-of-dlls-with-usercontrols

Comment: What? Where will you include that? it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: `Solution`: Don't mix different versions of `the same thing` (no matter what it is) in the same project.

Comment: I need to mix. The Component wich I use is the WPF Designer from Sharp Develop. And I also use Sharp Develop for Development! So I have the Designer Component in my Project, and the Designer Component in SD. And I cannot always update the version in my Project to the one wich SD is using at the Moment, so I have two Versions wich are loaded when I want to use the Designer to Design my Windows...

Comment: Your Solution is no Solution...
I only wanted to know, is that possible, does anyone know that? MSBuild need to know from somewhere wich version it should creates?

Comment: Is there no step wich happens after WPF Code generation before compiling, and a way to get the Version string??

Comment: Are you still dealing with this? dude, get Visual Studio 2013 Express or something...

Comment: I use the Designer DLL in another App. I'm not searching for another Program, I'm searching if it is possible or not...