# Set resource URI of .xaml component

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, uri

I have a .xaml UserControl named MyUserControl.xaml and I want to set its resource URI.

Per default, WPF generates a URI that includes a resource name, which is equal to the resource it belongs to such as

`"/MyNamespace;component/myusercontrol.xaml"`

for the .xaml named `MyUserControl.xaml`

How can I have a UserControl `MyUserControl.xaml` and make WPF generate an individual resource identifies such as

`"/MyNamespace;component/myusercontrol_A.xaml"` or
`"/MyNamespace;component/myusercontrol_B.xaml"` ?

The reason why I want to do that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044804/creating-multiple-xaml-views/35049213#35049213).

In the image below you can see the resource identifier I am talking about:

[image]

and therein:

[image]

Comment: "/MyNamespace;component/myusercontrol.xaml" is a path in your dll.. wpf doesnt generate anything...

Comment: Ok, but then how to set it?

Comment: its a path, you do not set it.. please take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044804/creating-multiple-xaml-views) is the origin of this question and might help to understand its background.

After a week suffering and laboring with this issue, I finally found both the reason for the problem and its solution.

The problem lies within the auto-generated `*.g.i.cs` file, which is called by the `InitializeComponent()` method of a `UserControl`, as seen by the following:

[image]

This file generates a string (a Resource Locator) that expresses the path to that xaml-component, as seen by the following:

[image]

Now, if you have **multiple versions of the same assembly** and both versions include the same xaml-file, *WPF* does not know what xaml-file to instantiate, because the Resource Locator only references the name of the assembly but not its version.

This results in a `TargetInvocationException`, saying that

> {"The component 'MyNamespace.MyUserControl' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/MyAssembly;comoponent/myusercontrol.xaml'"}

as follows:

[image]

The simple (but most definitely not obvious) solution for this is to add the version of the assembly to this Resource Locator. This can be achieved by modifying the build-file of the project by adding the `<AssemblyVersion>`-tag as follows:

[image]

Credits for this go to:

- [this blog](https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/microsoft-mechanism-to-load-wpf-resources-is-broken-looking-for-a-better-title/)
- [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453107/how-to-force-wpf-to-use-resource-uris-that-use-assembly-strong-name-argh/26689750#26689750)